# Using google ads developer token in multiple Apps

Tags: google-ads-api

I have an App that connects to the Google ads account of the user after finishing the Oauth2 login. It runs as Google Console Project. I want to create a different App in the new Console Project. Can I use the same developer token or should I create a new one? Some clarification I am not completely sure about the definition of console project for example if I go to the https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-resource-manager I can see many projects under No organization including the two apps I am talking about. Is each of them a different Console Project or are all of them under one console project and can use the same developer token?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The different projects you see are indeed different GCP projects.

The wording on the [relevant documentation page](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/first-call/dev-token) isn't 100% clear, but I understand it to mean that you must use **different projects** for **different developer tokens**, but can use the **same developer** token for **multiple projects**. At least the second part works for us when working with the (deprecated) Adwords API.

Comment: I hope it also works on ads api since adwords api will stop work in a year or so

Answer (score 0):

So for those who are also looking for an answer, I asked official Google support and here is a response I got.

> Only one developer token is generally given to a single legal entity, so it must be used across multiple apps. Other credentials such as the client ID, client secret and refresh token may also be used across multiple apps.